# wpf borderbrush binding in itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, border, itemscontrol

I have a Border inside an ItemsControl which needs to get it's BorderBrush from a field called BorderColor in the ItemsSource (an Observable Collection).

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ObsColOfThings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColor}">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The binding is working but the border brush is not.

I've also tried this and it doesn't work either despite the text working fine

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColor" BorderThickness="3">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AppointmentDescription}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to specify the `ItemTemplate` and the ContentPresenter's `ContentTemplate` of an ItemsControl at the same time, because the ItemTemplate effectively replaces the ContentTemplate.

Drop the entire `ItemContainerStyle` and write your ItemsControl like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ObsColOfThings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColor}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The type of the `BorderColor` property should be `Brush`:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Brush BorderColor { get; set; }
}
```

and then it should of course be called `BorderBrush`, not `BorderColor`.